# Protractor with several it failing

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a Protractor test with several it's. When I run each test individually (replace it with xit), every test Works fine. However when I run all the it's, it starts failing at number 3.

BTW, I searched and found several with the same issue, but the solution seems to not apply to my case. In the others I found, people suggested that the button was hidden (so it was not clickable), or that it was shown "off screen" (so the user had to scroll first to make the button visible), etc. I am absolutely sure the button is html-visible, enabled, and visible in the viewport.

The error shown is as follows:

```
1) e2e tests para admin/afps debería efectuar una búsqueda por código de afp = 2 
- Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (882, 169).
Other element would receive the click: <img class="pg-loading-logo" 
src="content/images/salfacorp3.jpg"> (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431
(9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 
x86_64)
```

The other errors are similar. The relevant part of the error is that `element is not clickable`, but when I run the tests one by one, the errors do not appear. Should there be some kind of a `pause` between tests? Any other ideas?

My conf.js file is as follows:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();

        var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
        // add jasmine spec reporter
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ displayStacktrace: 'all' }));
    },

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['../specs/salfa_spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        allowColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
        print: function () { }
    }
};
```

My specs file is as follows:
    'use strict';
    var AngularPage = require('../pageObjects/afps.page.js');

```
describe("e2e tests para admin/afps", function () {
    var page;// = require('../pageObjects/afps.page.js');

    beforeEach(function () {
        //browser.get("http://corporativo%5c79364193:Ariel2906@172.20.1.243/#/admin/afps");
        page = new AngularPage();
    });

    afterEach(function () {

    });

    it("debería estar en el mantenedor de afps", function () {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("/admin/afps");
    });

    it("debería efectuar una búsqueda por código de afp = 2", function () {
        page.searchById("2");

        expect(page.table.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);

        page.table.then(function (rows) {
            var rowElements = rows[0].all(by.css("td"));
            rowElements.then(function (cols) {
                expect(cols[2].getText()).toEqual("HABITAT");
            });
        });

    });

    it("debería efectuar una búsqueda por nombre de afp = cuprum", function () {
        page.searchByName("cuprum");
        expect(page.table.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);

        page.table.then(function (rows) {
            var rowElements = rows[0].all(by.css("td"));
            rowElements.then(function (cols) {
                expect(cols[2].getText()).toEqual("CUPRUM");
            });
        });


    });

    it("debería traer todas las AFPs", function () {
        page.txtSearchCodigo.click();
        //browser.driver.sleep(500);
        page.btnSearch.click();

        expect(page.table.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

    it("debería seleccionar la primera AFP, abrir la ventana de edición y modificar el valor de 'cotización SIS'", function () {
        page.txtSearchCodigo.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(500);
        page.btnSearchClick.then(function () {
            page.table.get(0).click();
            //expect(page.cotizacionSis.getAttribute('value')).toBe('3');
            page.cotizacionSis.clear();
            page.cotizacionSis.sendKeys(Math.random());
            page.btnUpdate.click();
        });

    });


});
```

And the page file is as follows:
    'use strict';

```
var AngularPage = function () {
     browser.get('http://corporativo%5c79364193:Ariel2906@172.20.1.243/#/admin/afps');
 };

AngularPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    txtSearchCodigo: { get: function () { return element(by.id("txtSearchCodigo")); } },
    txtSearchNombre: { get: function () { return element(by.id("txtSearchNombre")); } },
    btnSearch: { get: function () { return element.all(by.css(".btn-primary")).first(); } },
    btnUpdate: { get: function () { return element.all(by.css(".btn-primary")).last(); } },
    table: { get: function () { return element.all(by.repeater("item in vm.afps")); } },
    cotizacionSis: { get: function () { return element(by.id("txtEditCotizacionIsis")); } },

    searchById: {
        value: function (codigo) {
            this.txtSearchCodigo.sendKeys(codigo);
            this.btnSearch.click();
        }
    },

    searchByName: {
        value: function (name) {
            this.txtSearchNombre.sendKeys(name);
            this.btnSearch.click();
        }
    }
});

module.exports = AngularPage;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error does it throws?

Comment: Sorry, by bad. I added the error description and also the Protractor conf.js. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like a *timing issue* and there is sort of a "loading" spinner/animation. Try add `browser.wait()` calls with the [`elementToBeClickable` expected condition](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable).

Comment: That's exactly wht it was. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the issue based on @alecxe recomendation. I'm sharing in case it can be usefull for anyone facing the same issue. I added the following code to the `beforeEach` block:

```
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var elm = element.all(by.css('[ng-click="vm.searchMainEntities();"]')).first();
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 10000);
```

This allowed the app to finish loading before executing the button click.